# Insert trigger for invoice table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have an `Invoice` table with columns `[customer no.]`, `amount` and `[invoice no.]`.

I have to create a separate numbering of invoices per client, i.e. for client 1 we have invoices 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 ... 1 / n and for each subsequent client k/n.

For example, for query

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Invoice] ([customer no.], [amount])
VALUES (1, 123.23), (1, 323.23), (2, 123.23), (3, 123.23), (4, 123.23)
```

the `[invoice no.]` column should get values `1/1`, `1/2`, `2/1`, `3/1`, `4/1`.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: And what happens when an invoice is deleted? Think carefully about your actual goal before you start writing code.

Comment: This is something that can be created by a query when it's required.  I don't see any need to store this

Comment: @SMor Nothing happens.

Comment: So learn to write a trigger as a first step. Lots of tutorials and examples exist if you search. A sequence might be a better approach along with a computed column (or a view) to "format" this information as you desire.

Comment: Definitely a sequence and computed column... far less complexity than a trigger.